# VBA Application.OnTimeime not looping

Tags: excel, vba

am a newbie here. Thanks in advance for your help :)

I've got a simple code to run a countdown timer, from 5 seconds to zero seconds using Application.OnTime.

However, if I set the code in a For loop, say to run the timer 10 times, by resetting it back to 5 seconds after every run, the timer just runs once and skips from 5 seconds straight to zero seconds. It completely ignores the following loops. Here's the code...

```
Sub Times()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
Range("D14").Value = TimeValue("12:00:05 AM")
startTimer
Next i
End Sub

Sub startTimer()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Minus_second"
End Sub

Sub Minus_second()
If Range("d14").Value = 0 Then Exit Sub
Range("d14").Value = Range("d14").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
startTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: perhaps a DO UNTIL loop would work better?

Comment: Try removing the loop in "Times"

Comment: Yeah I was a bit confused I don't know why you have the loop unless you're trying to count down for 25 seconds? Otherwise your timer is taking care of itself fine (Count down 5 seconds from 12:00:05 to 12:00:00)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Basically, I'm trying to countdown from 5 secs to Zero seconds, and do this 5 times by resetting the timer to 5 seconds when it reaches zero.

Comment: For some reason, when I run it without the loop it runs perfectly fine from 5 to Zero. But when I try to loop it 5 times, by resetting the time at the start of each loop, it just stops (jumps from 5 secs to Zero secs for 1 loop only). It seems fairly simple, but I can't to figure out where its going crazy! :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop, try this:

```
Sub someMacro()

    Range("D14") = TimeValue("12:00:05 AM")  'set initial time
    countdownTimer   'begin countdown

End Sub


Sub countdownTimer()

    increment = TimeValue("00:00:01")   'adjust here, currently one second increments

    With Range("D14")   'same range as in the above calling macro
        If .value = 0 Then Exit Sub 'once time reaches 12:00:00 then exit
        .value = .value - increment
    End With

    Application.OnTime Now + increment, "countdownTimer"

End Sub
```

*A loop executes so fast that it basically runs all 5 instances of the macro at the same time, which is why it looks like it ran only once

**Edited solution:** (as per requirements in below comments)

```
Option Explicit

Dim targetCell As Range
Dim timerLimit As Date
Dim increment As Date
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long

Sub initializeTimers()

'Adjust parameters here:
Set targetCell = Range("D14")    'cell in which the countdown displays
n = 5 'number of times to run the countdown timer
timerLimit = 5  'seconds to countdown from in each cycle
increment = 1   'countdown increment in seconds

    increment = Format(TimeSerial(0, 0, increment), "hh:mm:ss")
    i = 0

    resetCountdownTimer
    countdownTimer

End Sub

Sub resetCountdownTimer()

    targetCell = Format(TimeSerial(0, 0, timerLimit), "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub

Sub countdownTimer()

    With targetCell
        If .value = 0 Then
            If i < n Then
                i = i + 1
                resetCountdownTimer
                Application.OnTime Now + increment, "countdownTimer"   'try this or the below line
                'Application.OnTime Now, "countdownTimer"   'strictly 5 seconds
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Exit Sub 'once time reaches 12:00:00 then exit
            End If
        End If
        .value = .value - increment
    End With

    Application.OnTime Now + increment, "countdownTimer"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks jblack! But I need the count down timer (of 5 seconds) to run 5 times. So for a total of 25 seconds, in 5 second loops.